# Google Visualization API Not Respecting GID or Sheet Parameter

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

I'm using the Google Visualization Javascript API to load a Chart from Google Sheets and display it in a div. My app is hosted on Google App Engine. I provide the URL to the sheet with the parameter `gid=1` to specify the second sheet but the chart the gets displayed is the first sheet. Here's my simplified code (it's basically the example code provided in the documentation):

```
// sheetUrl is the URL of the Google sheet, e.g., http://https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AobNU9T3MusKdGFqRHNJYkFnb3RuSkt4QlE#gid=1
// divId is the id of the <div> element I'm displaying in

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {packages: ['table']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(sheetUrl);
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {

    var data = response.getDataTable();
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById(divId));
    table.draw(data);
}
```

You can see the `#gid=1` in the URL. I've also tried `&gid=1` and `&sheet='Volume'`, which is the name of the tab but when the page loads, the data from the first tab gets rendered.

I have noticed Google sheet urls in the form I have above but also in this form:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=0AobNU9T3MusKdGFqRHNJYkFnb3RuSkt4QlE
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation explicitly explaining the tq endpoint. I tried using a URL in this form but I get timeout error when trying to load the chart. Any one run into this problem or have insight in the tq thing? Thanks!

*Edit 2014-02-17:*

I've changed my URL to use the tq endpoint and I've tried the following parameters:

```
#gid=1
&gid=1
#sheet=Volume
&sheet=Volume
```

When I query for the url in the browser:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=0AobNU9T3MusKdGFqRHNJYkFnb3RuSkt4QlE&sheet=Volume
```

I get the appropriate sheet back. But when I use the Visualization API to query, I get the first sheet.

Answer (score 8):

The correct URL to pass to the Visualization API that will work with the new Google Sheets is this format:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{key}/gviz/tq
```

You can use the `gid` query parameter to pass the ID of the worksheet you want to retrieve. So if your `gid` is 0, the URL would be:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{key}/gviz/tq?gid=0
```

You can find additional information regarding URL formats for both the old and new Google Sheets in [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1476).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

Referencing by sheet name also works as in

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{key}/gviz/tq?sheet=MySheetName
```

Make sure spreadsheet is "new" vs "old" Google Sheets. I banged my head on that one as I thought my sheet was new. Once I created a new style sheet and used donnapep answer I was working again. I then confirmed using sheet=sheetname works as well which was what I was really after.